# Effect of styles on component contents

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

This is a basic CSS question, but I need to confirm something. Lets say I have the following:

```
 <v-app id="inspire">

<v-container justify-center style="max-width: 1200px">
          <v-layout row justify-space-around>

    <v-flex justify-center >
      <v-expansion-panel style="max-width: 1200px">
        <v-expansion-panel-content v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i">
          <div slot="header">{{item.header}}</div>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-text>{{item.text}}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-expansion-panel-content>
      </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

With regard to :

```
<v-container justify-center style="max-width: 1200px">
```

I assume the properties (justify-center and style="max-width: 1200px") apply to the contexts of the v-container , but not the v-container itself. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**justify-center** it's applied to the content inside the **v-container** while the **max-width** apply to the v-container itself

Comment: Thank you. I don't know much about css frameworkd or css. How do you know this?

Comment: As you are using Vuetify classes you're missing the CSS property that in this case would be "justify-content=center;" that defines how the browser distributes space between and around content items along the main axis of a flex container, and the inline axis of a grid container.

You can read more about [here](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

On the other hand, "max-width" sets the maximum width of an element.

You can read more [here](http://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!